# What to do when the chebyshev point is equal to data point in lagrange interpolation?

Tags: interpolation, chebyshev-polynomials

I am going to use Lagrange interpolation using Chebyshev nodes using the following formula

$$\sum_x \prod_{k=0,k\not={j}}^n \frac {x-y_k}{y_j-y_k} f(x) $$

in which $x$ in my data points, $y_k $s are my chebyshev points. It could happen that the $x$ and $y_k$ be equal so the product will be zero. What I have to do in these situations? Should I use the zero value or put something else instead?

Answer (score 2):

If $x = y_j \in X$ ($X$ Chebyshev grid) we want that all Lagrange polynomials cancels except the polynomial associated to the node $y_j$ that we want be equal to $1$.

This is the only way to verify to have:
$$\Pi_nf(x) := \sum_{j = 0}^n\left( f(y_j)  \prod_{k=0,k\not={j}}^n \frac {x-y_k}{y_j-y_k} \right) $$
equal to $f(y_j)$. In fact, if $x= y_j$ every term of the sum cancels except the $j$-th and so we get the result.

Comment: How about the edit I have done, In this situation what should I do?

Comment: I don't understand... What is that formula? Look at my formula, this is the expression of the interpolating polynomial. Where is the problem?